# Why we have two data model static and dynamic in lwc to refer in metadata aware component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

In base lightning component in LWC we can refer data model static or dynamic.

Static ensures referential integrity whereas dynamic does not. 
Is there any other difference between these two? Which one is faster and what other difference these two have.

Comment: Static would be faster as the type checking would happen at compiletime